# Installing Apache Passenger , Ruby Development Headers Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, apache2, passenger

I have a RoR app that needs to be hosted on Apache, so I have been trying to install Apache Passenger. When I run the following command:

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I get:

```
Checking for required software...

 * GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
 * Curl development headers with SSL support... found
 * OpenSSL development headers... found
 * Zlib development headers... found
 * Ruby development headers... not found
 * OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
 * RubyGems... found
 * Rake... found at /usr/local/bin/rake
 * rack... found
 * Apache 2... found at /usr/sbin/apache2
 * Apache 2 development headers... found at /usr/bin/apxs2
 * Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers... found at /usr/bin/apr-1-config
 * Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers... found at /usr/bin/apu-1-config
```

So it asked me to run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

and I have done this with the following result

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ruby1.8-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
```

So when I run:

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I get the same result asking me to run:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

Comment: Could you try a later version of ruby? Or install with rvm?

Comment: Which version of Enterprise Ruby did you download? Also I'm assuming you're using some Debian-based Linux distro: Ubuntu? Mint? Please clarify - I'll try all that in a virtual. I'm running Ubuntu and Mint and Ubuntu server - never had any problems with passenger installation....

Answer (score 13):

If, like me, you are running the apt package ruby1.9.1 instead of 1.8 then install ruby1.9.1-dev instead

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

This worked for me.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

After installing the missing headers, go back to the beginning and recompile passenger:

```
gem install passenger
```

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling ruby1.9 and installing ruby1.8 instead then reinstall the passenger gem. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**First install packages:**

- for Ubuntu:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
  sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
  ```
- for CentOS (good [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6)):

  ```
  yum install curl-devel apache2-devel
  ```

**After install gem:**

```
gem install passenger
```

**And successfully configurate it:**

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that with some Passenger requirements you need to log out of and then log back into the current user after you've installed them before passenger-install-apache2-module recognises the changed configuration.