# Cannot install passenger due to Ruby development headers not found

Tags: ruby, rvm, passenger

Running `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module`, I get:

```
Checking for required software...

 * GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
 * The 'make' tool... found at /usr/bin/make
 * A download tool like 'wget' or 'curl'... found at /usr/bin/wget
 * Ruby development headers... not found
```

No luck with

> Please run `apt-get install ruby1.8-dev` as root

Comment: Why do you have no luck with "run apt-get install ruby1.8-dev as root"? Have you tried it? What was the result? If you got an error message what was it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Apache Passenger , Ruby Development Headers Not Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334984/installing-apache-passenger-ruby-development-headers-not-found)

Comment: @theTinMan FYI ruby 1.8 is no more maintained, it should not be used if it's not required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried:

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
gem install passenger
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Comment: Don't `rvm get head` unless you need to, instead use `rvm get stable`.

Comment: actually if you have issues - `rvm get head` is required before reporting errors, a lot of time the issue is already fixed

Comment: i think i messed up with `rvmsudo gem install passenger` instead just `gem install passenger` what is the diff?

Comment: @mpapis But it shouldn't be the *first* thing you try.